# uniScaleTransform property is not working?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I do not want uniform scaling at corner points so i have added uniScaleTransform property to true at the time of initiation but it is not working , still it's scaling uniformly.I am using fabric js version 1.6.3, below is the code,

```
<!-- fabric js code-->

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
        uniScaleTransform : true
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I've added a working example below that seem to work fine. If you are seeing different results please do post a snippet of working code demonstrating the problem.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { uniScaleTransform : true, preserveObjectStacking:true });

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 50, 
  height: 50, 
  fill: '#faa', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 300, 
  top: 300, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: I think i am not clear between uniform and non-uniform scaling. Can you please explain me what is the difference between them? What i need is when i drag any one corner instead of that corresponding edge getting expanded , i need only that corner needs to be moved to get irregular polygon, like free drawing.

Comment: `uniScaleTransform` only applies to the 4 corner handles. `true` means you can make the shape bigger or small but not distort it, so a square stays a square. `false` means you can distort it and turn a square in to a rectangle or a circle into an oval.

Comment: I think you have explained in reverse manner, true means we can distort it and false means we can't since in your code it is true and we can turn circle to oval.

Comment: As one workaroun... The property can be set to the rectangle object iself, as .lockUniScaling = true; with Fabric JS, rather than trying to apply it to the whole canvas...